# PHP- compare similarity score in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, sentiment-analysis

This is my PHP code to show similarity score(positive/negative/neutral) for each text.

```
foreach ($dict as $key => $cat) {
        $similarity[$key] = $Product[$key] / ($lengthQ * $lengthC[$key]);
        echo "Similarity score($key): ". $similarity[$key]. "<br/>";
        echo "---------";
    }
```

How can it show the result from comparing the similarity score(`$similarity[$key]`) and print the category(`$key`) which is the highest score.

The expected output:

> Similarity score(positive): 0.029764673182427
>
> Similarity score(negative): 0.020378478648481
>
> Similarity score(neutral): 0.057639041770423
>
> neutral
>
> ---
>
> Similarity score(positive): 0.028088336282316
>
> Similarity score(negative): 0.019230769230769
>
> Similarity score(neutral): 0.054392829322042
>
> neutral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the maximum value with `max()` then search on that value to get the key with `array_search()`:

```
echo array_search(max($similarity), $similarity);
```